How can I fix a '500 Internal Server Error' in my PHP WordPress site?
I'm building a custom WordPress theme, and I'm encountering a '500 Internal Server Error' when trying to access the site."
After updating my functions.php file, I started getting a '500 Internal Server Error' instead of the homepage. I expected the changes to be reflected without errors."

look into the error log.

500 Internal Server Error is a generic error meaning your server-side code crashed, but it doesn't tell you how, where or why it crashed. Enable error reporting (or logging) in PHP and then check for the detailed error message which will give you a real clue about the problem. Nobody can tell you anything just from the 500 error.

Frankly, from reading your profile and all the experience you say you've got, this is something you should surely already know and would have seen before...
